# if $H$ and $K$ are arbitrary groups, show that $H \times K \cong K \times H$

Tags: abstract-algebra

if $H$ and $K$ are arbitrary groups, show that $H \times K \cong K \times H$. My attempt is define a map $f:H \times K \rightarrow K \times H$ such that $f((h,k))=(k^{-1},h^{-1})$. Then I try to show that map is bijective and homomorphism. But the map given in the answer is $f((h,k))=(k,h)$. I would like to ask is my way of mapping correct ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I can't make comments)
Does your map work if the groups are not abelian?

Comment: ooh, thx for your comment. I know what's wrong with my map

Comment: +1 - now you can make comments. And @Idonknow: then you need to consider changing your user name. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yours is fine too. However, the map suggested in the answer is probably the first to come to mind, and maybe a tad easier to show. But if you think you proved your suggestion fully, then yours works too.

Comment: Moral: don't answer questions at 5am. This is not true.

Comment: Who did you leave a comment above? Did you answer this question at 5am? I see you are addicted to MSE like me. :)

Comment: @BabakS.: I left it around 5am, right before going to bed. Addicted? Me? Never...

Comment: Any way, I hope you have a nice time. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

1. Is your map a group homomorphism? I mean $f(h_1h_2, k_1,k_2) = f(h_1,k_1)f(h_2,k_2)?$

Comment: $f((h_1,k_1),(h_2,k_2))=f((h_1 h_2, k_1 k_2))=((k_1 k_2)^{-1} , (h_1 h_2)^{-1})=(k_2^{-1} k_1^{-1}, h_2^{-1} h_1^{-1})=f(h_1,k_1).f(h_2,k_2)$

Comment: ooh, I know what's wrong with my map. If $H \times K$ is not abelian, then the map is not homomorphism.

Comment: @Idonknow: How do you define $(a,b)(c,d)$?Is it $(ac,bd)$ or $(ca,db)$?

Comment: @BabakS.: $(a.b)(c.d)=(ac,bd)$

Comment: @Idonknow: So; why did you write $(k_2^{-1}k_1^{-1},h_2^{-1}h_1^{-1})=(k_1^{-1},h_1^{-1}).(k_2^{-1},h_2^{-1})$  instead of $(k_2^{-1},h_2^{-1}).(k_1^{-1},h_1^{-1})$? See the last identity in your first comment above.

Comment: ooh, thx for pointing out